# Integral of the level curve $ye^{2x}$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

$\int_{0}^{2}\int_{0}^{4} ye^{2x}$ $dydx$

The book says the answer is $32(e^4-1)$
I had to do u-substitution when doing it, maybe that's where I went wrong.

First integrating with respect to y, holding $e^{2x}$ as a constant and plugging in gives me:
$\int_0^2\int_0^4 \frac{1}{2}y^2e^{2x} \Big\vert_0^4 \to \int_0^2 8e^{2x}dx$

This quit clearly calls for u substitution here, from what I remember 2x is a function inside of $f(x)=e^x$ where $g(x)=2x$ and $f(g(x))=e^{2x}$:

$u=2x$

$du=2dx \to \frac{1}{2}du=dx$

Getting my bounds: $u(2)=4$ and $u(0)=0$

My new integral is:
$\int_0^4 \frac{1}{2} (8)e^u$ $\to$ $\int_0^4 4e^u \Big\vert_0^4=4e^8-4=4(e^8-1)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The book is wrong, your derivation is also wrong.

Note that you substitute $u=8$ instead of $u=4$. You already changed the bounds to integrate from $u=0$ to $4$. The correct answer is $4(e^4 - 1)$.

$\int_0^4 \frac{1}{2} (8)e^u du$ $\to$ $\int_0^4 4e^u du \Big\vert_0^4=4e^\color{red}{4}-4=4(e^\color{red}{4}-1)$

Comment: Could you show the work as to why $u=8$ instead of $u=4?$ Since $2(2)=4$ ,  $2(2) \neq 8$

Comment: No, you should substitute $u=4$. If you look at your work, you've substituted $u=8$.

Comment: If you are talking about the last line  i got 8 from dy when I plugged in my upper bound 4 squared it and got 16 divided by $\frac{1}{2}$ I don't think im following

Comment: Oh i follow i plugged in 4 into $u\to$ $u=2(x)=2(4)=8$

Comment: So when I plug in my bounds I am not plugging in 4 for x in 2x which is u I think I am lost as to the correct whay of plugging in my bounds with u

Comment: You plug in 2 for x, because that was what your original bounds were. Since $u=2x$, that's plugging in $u=4$.

Answer (score 0):

Slight error in your final line. The original x limits were 0 and 2 which changed to 0 and 4 for u. However you seemed to have doubled them again when substituting into $4e^u$.